# OWA 2013 doesn't allow logins

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

We have recently migrated to Exchange 2013 and everything seemed to be ok. Users can access their mailboxes via Outlook and via ActiveSync on their phones and OWA was tested and working.

However this week when trying to access via OWA users are entering their usernames and passwords and it is returning:

> The user name or password you entered isn't correct. Try entering it
>   again.

This is happening for all users in the company. It was working for all users last week. I have noticed in the event log the following error which I think is related but I don't know how to fix:

> the service '/EWS/exchange.asmx' cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not
>   find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with
>   binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]..

What do I need to change to allow OWA to login again?

Comment: Are all of your Exchange services running?

Comment: @JeremyLyons Yes they are all running

Comment: This applies to Exchange 2010, but it might give you some guidance. Are you able to log in using HTTPS?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2009/12/22/how-to-configure-a-http-endpoint-for-exchange-web-services-in-exchange-2010.aspx

Comment: I'm getting this problem on HTTPS